# How to display a custom verbose_name on a GenericForeignKey in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to display a custom field name (perhaps translated) for a `GenericForeignKey` field of a model in **Django admin**.

Unfortunately, a `GenericForeignKey` does not accept `verbose_name` (at least in Django 1.6), so how would I actually add a custom name in the admin?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show custom name of field in list (not in add/edit form) just try this in admin.py

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('field1', 'custom_field')

    def custom_field(self, obj):
        return obj.real_field

    custom_field.short_description = u'Custom name'
```

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to avoid @kirill-kartashov 's method, so I experimented a bit with `short_description` attribute.

And I found that, apparently, you can add a `short_description` attr. directly to the GenericForeignKey like so:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class SomeModel(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, null=True)
    object_id = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True)
    related_field = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id',)

    related_field.short_description = _('My related field')
```